# Why does this function return different values on repeated calls?

Tags: python, recursion

```
memory = {}
def rec(n):
    if n in memory:
        value = n
    elif n == 1:
        value = 1
    elif n == 2:
        value = 1
    elif n > 2:
        value = rec(n - 2) + rec(n - 1)
    memory[n] = value
    return value
```

This is the code, and I know it is not entirely a correct recursion code. What I do not understand is that if I call rec(5), it output 7 at the first time, and 5 from the next time. Please can someone help me explain this?

Comment: Can you please clearly state your question? I am not sure what the problem is…

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank it was there, but due to a formatting issue `<memory` is was not shown ;)

Comment: Why does this code output 7 at the first time

Comment: use rec(5) to call the function and output 7. I do not understand this.

Comment: @joijioj see my answer for explanation

Comment: It returns different results because it uses global variable `memory` to store some state.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is you're updating memory when n is already in the memory. The whole process of your first `rec(5)` is:

`rec(5) = rec(3) + rec(4) = rec(1) + rec(2) + rec(4) = 1 + 1 + rec(2) + rec(3)`

Until here everything is correct. Then your method will calculate `rec(2)` where 2 is already in your `memory`, so your new value for `rec(2)` is 2.

If you don't understand why, see here:

```
def rec(n):
    if n in memory:
        value = n
    # ...
    memory[n] = value
    return value
```

Then it calculates the value of `rec(3)`, and 3 is also in memory, so `rec(3)` is now 3

Then `rec(5) = 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 7`

For the second time you run it, since 5 is in memory, so the output is 5.

One possible solution:

```
def rec(n):
    if n in memory:
        return memory[n]
    elif n == 1:
        value = 1
    elif n == 2:
        value = 1
    elif n > 2:
        value = rec(n - 2) + rec(n - 1)
    memory[n] = value
    return value
```

Comment: This is so clear bro. I was keep updating the memory no matter if I used it before. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @joijioj No worries. Next time you saw this kind of bug you can print the important variables (in this case, the `memory`) out, then you could debug by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
memory = {}
def rec(n):
    if n in memory:
        value = memory[n]
    elif n == 1:
        value = 1
    elif n == 2:
        value = 1
    elif n > 2:
        value = rec(n - 2) + rec(n - 1)
    memory[n] = value

    return value

print (rec(5))
print (rec(5))
```

Now it prints 5 both times. The problem was with value=n while it should be

```
value=memory[n],
```

So,

```
value=n
```

meant that the value of 2 too gets updated to 2.